# C# не видит класс Stopwatch

Tags: c#

Я хочу использовать класс Stopwatch. Подключил System.Diagnostics.
Однако при попытке создать экземпляр класса Stopwatch, Visual Studio пишет, что не удалось найти тип или пространство имён "Stopwatch".

Comment: Без вашего кода не видно что вы сделали не так. Приведите пожалуйста минимальный пример воспроизводящий проблему.

Comment: @rdorn Там простое объявление Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch(). Остальной код довольно большой, не думаю что он как-то может на это повлиять.

Comment: Возможны у вас не добавлена ссылка System. Хотя по-умолчанию при создании проекта она должна быть. Посмотрите где добавить ссылки и где сборки найди System, галочка должна стоять.
Сборки:
System.Runtime.Extensions.dll, System.dll, netstandard.dll

Comment: @Sergey_73 Спасибо большое! Помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Пишет тип или пространство имён не существует в пространстве имён "System.Diagnostics"

скорее всего отсутствует какой-то референс в проэкте. 
Предполагаю что пофиксится если добавить System.dll в референсы или в референсах проставить галочку возле System.

Но если не найдешь как это сделать.... наверное, самым простым способом для тебя будет просто пересоздать проэкт. Проследить что бы там был выбран нужный .Net framework , но не проэкты других типов и не трогать лишних галочек в настройках проэкта при создании... И просто скопировать код из старого проэкта. Самая вероятная причина даной проблемы состоит в том, что ты не то наклацал при создании проэкта.